# My Nokia Lumia 520 won't play YouTube videos

Tags: lumia-520

Everytime I load a video it says Decode Error. My phone is up-to-date and I still have 3,75 GB left so I really don't understand the issue. Any advice?

Comment: Are you using an app or the website? The website (in HTML5 mode, Desktop version of the site) works perfectly for me. Did it ever work before?

Comment: I'm using the website. It worked perfectly fine a sec ago it just stopped working properly and idk why.

Comment: Odd... have you rebooted the phone?

Comment: Nope my screen broke so I got it fixed recently, but that's all.

Comment: try using UC browser(Speed mode off) !! hope it will work

Answer (score 2):

Go to Internet Explorer and tap on the three dots in the bottom right corner of the screen of the screen. Go to Settings > Website Preference. If it is set to "Mobile version" change it to "Desktop version." Then go back to the YouTube website and try again.

Answer (score 2):

I also started getting a message that my 7.5 HTC phone couldn't play videos (when it used to). In frustration today, I cleaned out internet explorer history and then turned my phone off and then on again. Problem solved...finally able to watch videos after 3 months. I clean my browsers history on my laptop all the time...can't believe I forgot to do that with my phone! Apparently 2+ years of inattention is not a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

My windows phone video play only showed decode error. I cleared the internet explorer total history and turned windows phone off. Then 5 minuted after turned it on. Then problem solved. The phone was able to play YouTube videos.